# AIX 5.3 - Howto backup operating system to a bootable ISO image

Tags: aix

We would like to backup the AIX 5.3 IntelliStation at our company. Unfortunately it does not have a tapedrive nor a DVD-Writer. It only has a DVD-ROM drive.

The idea is to mount a directory via NFS and to create an ISO image there. Afterwards We would use a different machine to create a bootable DVD from the ISO image.

How can this be done? I have tried the mkdvd command from a smitty terminal, but it seems that mkdvd does not accept a filename, e.g. /nfsmount/aixbackup/system-image.iso.

Any help on this is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meanwhile I found out how to create a bootable DVD .iso image.

Instructions:

```
unset LC_ALL

# note: I have unmounted /home before creating the iso image. Otherwise I would need multiple DVDs

# note: I have mounted an NFS directory below /volumes/aixsav
extdir=/volumes/aixsav

# create some needed subdirectories
for i in mksysb_target tmp iso mkcd; do
       test -d $extdir/$i || mkdir $extdir/$i || exit 1
done

# finally: create the .iso image.
/usr/sbin/mkdvd -M $extdir/mksysb_target -C $extdir/tmp -I $extdir/iso -S
```

This needs some time. But after all I had my image in the iso subdirectory. I went to another machine and burned the image to a DVD (under linux).

For testing I have shut down the AIX machine and replaced the existing harddisk with a another empty one. Then I booted up and followed the onscreen instruction for restoring from DVD.

Everything went fine. Even the Usernames/Passwords, Hostname, IP-Address everything was like on the original harddrive!

a final note: be patient! creating the Image and booting from the DVD will need some time. Just lay back and wait ...

Answer (score 1):

Mkdvd can be used for this.
It will take the rootvg (or a backup made with mksysb) and will write it on the specified device.

To create a bootable dvd, you can simply use the following:

```
mkdvd -d /dev/cd1
```

You should have a look at [mkdvd](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/mkdvd.htm), [mksysb](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/mksysb.htm) and [savevg](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/savevg.htm) documentation before doing anything nasty on your server..